# What's the best way to redirect to a new wordpress website?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, hosting

I have the following case... I have two websites, two domains on two different hostings. I want to redirect the old domain to my new wordpress website, which uses a new domain and new urls for the pages and is on new hosting.

What is the best way to do this? My thoughts are I have two options:
1. I transfer the domain to the new hosting, making the redirects there.
2. I leave the old domain on the old hosting, making the redirects there. In that case I should keep paying for the old hosting or the redirects would be gone.

Am I missing something? Can you please let me know what's the best scenario here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a WP question and it'll likely get closed...anyway...your registrar should allow you to do an immediate redirect (called [domain forwarding](https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-a-domain-12123)), which will take care if it via DNS.  So, keep the domain but shut off the hosting service since you don't need it.

Updated:

The domain forwarding is a simple HTTP 301 response the registrar provides.    You'd need a second redirect at the new domain to get the incoming page to land where you want it to.  So for example:

```
Incoming:  www.olddomain.com/some-special-page
Registrar 301:  www.newdomain.com/some-special-page

Now, at newdomain:  Redirect 301 /some-special-page /my-new-page
```

Google does not penalize for 301 redirects so I would always try to do it via .htaccess.  If the plugin claims it's "SEO safe" and it is re-writing the response header then that's probably ok, too.

Comment: It is also kind of Wordpress question because my next question is can I do the redirects for the pages (since they have different urls) using the Seo Redirection plugin (after the domain is forwarded) or should I use htaccess?

Comment: any thoughts on this? Would the SEO redirection plugin be able to handle the redirects after I forward the domain?

Comment: updated answer...